# <SQL>Extract data from table which is txt format (contain 1 fields only)

Tags: sql, db2

In our exsiting system we have a table to store the reported user info (let's say UserInfoRaw), this table contains 1 fields (detail) only , the sample data would be sth like below:

```
^StartNewUser 
^UserName
Simon
^EnableFacebook
Y
^EnableTwitter
N
^EndNewUser
^StartNewUser
^UserName
Vicky
^EnableFacebook
N
^EndNewUser
```

Currently we need to convert this format to a query-able table, lets say "User-info" which contain below 3 fields , the output should be

```
    UserName          facebook          twitter
==================================================
    Simon                 Y                N
    Vicky                 N                N
```

The Constraint is

**1.** I do know the tage fields i need to extract (said , `^EnableFacebook` is a tag name that i know , can use for selection)
 **2.** We're extract by user level, for each user they MUST have `^StartNewUser/^EndNewUser` in the txt , this is pre-assumption.
 **3.** The attribute tag may not exist for some cases (eg , `Vicky's ^EnableTwitter` tag) , it should treat this field as N while extraction.
 **4.** We can use pure SQL here only as this is an interim solution for our MI Team , they can run SQL only and currently we can't do any program release to automate this process at this moment.

Currently we have come up a solution by RRN but need many interim table

1： Produce OUT1 which include the row number for start/end for each user

**`SELECT RRN(A) ,detail from UserInfoRaw A where A.detail in ('^StartNewUser' , '^EndNewUser')`**

## OUT1 ：

```
1           ^StartNewUser       
8           ^EndNewUser   
9           ^StartNewUser       
14          ^EndNewUser
```

2： Produce OUT2 which include the row number for user name

**`Select RRN(A) ,detail from UserInfoRaw A where RRN(A) IN
(select RRN(B)+1 from UserInfoRaw B where B.detail = '^UserName')`**

## OUT2 ：

```
3           Simon
11          Vicky
```

3： Produce JOIN12 which include the row mapping for ^StartNewUser / ^UserName

**`Select MAX(A.row) as startRow , B.row as nameRow from OUT1 A,OUT2 B 
where A.detail = '^StartNewUser' AND A.row <B.row 
GROUP BY B.row
order by A.row`**

## JOIN12 ：

```
1           3
9           11
```

4： Join 3 table by the row of ^startNewUser to get the 1 field mapping

**`Select C.startRow ,A.detail , C.nameRow,B.detail from OUT1 A, OUT2 B, JOIN12 C where A.row=C.startRow and B.row=C.nameRow`**

## Result ：

```
1       ^startNewUser     3     Simon
9       ^startNewUser     11    Vicky
```

By this approach we can produce a 1 field mapping , and using similar step we can get all the result field table we want.

But we have 10+ fields to extract (mayeb more if business request) , so we're seek help here to see if we have better idea for this case. Thanks!

(ps: if you're a AS400 guy and you know how to produce result by wrkqry that would be the best :) you know what MI team im referring to... really mess..)

Comment: in tsql you could solve this with the pivot-function quite smoothly. But db2 maybe doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Are these sample data from the question saved in one record? I mean the whole text you have shown in the question represent a single database row. Or maybe each of the lines of text is saved in a single database record?

Comment: @krokodilko it's different row , each of the lines of text is saved in a single database table but different row.

Comment: I would convert to json.  Its pretty close now.  Then query the json or use the json to create a table.

Comment: Why are you inventing ways to process xml or JSON looking files.

Answer (score -1):

By your own admission, you have a text file, not a table.

SQL wasn't designed to deal with files (text or otherwise), it was designed to deal with *databases*, containing tables and relations.

Therefore, don't use SQL statements for this, process it as a text file.  It's going to be faster and simpler.  My default assumption is that a traditional RPGLE program doing `READ` is going to beat any attempt to do this sort of processing in SQL, simply because this is the type of workload it was designed for.  Or use any other language that can process files.

(It would be easier to do this in SQL with a stored procedure and firing up a cursor, but it would be unwieldy at best, because SQL lacks many of the features makes doing this in a 'normal' programming language so much easier, like local, private functions)

## tl;dr

I have a hammer, what's the best way to use it to cut a board in half?

Comment: This isn't a helpful answer.